# How can I simulate a mousePressed event without using java.awt.robot?

Tags: java, mouseevent, awtrobot

I want to simulate a mousePressed event in Java, I found out that I can use the `Robot` class for this, and it works, but only in Windows and not in Mac OS X.

Does anyone know of an alternative way to simulate a `mousePressed` event?

This is the code I used:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Comment: AFAIC robot needs admin privileges to simulate native events on some systems.

Comment: I checked this link how a developer does it in Mac OSX: he put `robot.delay(200)` after `robot.mousePress()` method... I am not sure it works or not...I don't have a Apple computer: http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke

Comment: @eee I tried that, but doesn't solve it, I think the delay is only usefull when you want to simulate multiple actions one after another. So there's a pause between two simulated actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simulate the click action on a `JButton` you can invoke the `doClick` method,  take a look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CallbuttondoClickmethodtosimulateaclickaction.htm). Otherwise, maybe this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445105/how-do-you-simulate-a-click-on-a-jtextfield-equivalent-of-jbutton-doclick) can help you.
Hope this helps.

Comment: the 'doClick' method won't work, the click happens in a random part of  a JPanel. So maybe I need to create a mousepressedEvent wich I can send to the mousePressed method. I just don't know how.

Comment: The code for your `mousePressed` event should be in a `MouseAdapter` implementation. Can you invoke manually the method `mousePressed` of this object to simulate the event?

Comment: I already have a mouseAdapter implementation, I suppose you can invoke it manually but you'll need a mouseEvent parameter (I don't know if you can create those by hand).

Comment: It seems possible to create the `MouseEvent` by hand. You should take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785422/swing-send-an-event-programmatically) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800840/sending-keypresses-to-jtextfield). Good luck! :-)

Comment: I have been working on the custom events, and it should work, but after some debugging I found the real problem (I think). The problem is that I press the mouseButton on a part of a JPanel and this mousepress activates the glassPane, so I need something that transfers the current mousePressed event from the jpanels mouselistener to the glasspane mouseListener, but I'll post a new question for this problem. Thanks for your help javanna

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with using java.awt.robot.mousePress(int button) not working on a mac os x 10.8
by checking

```
int b = InputEvent.getMaskForButton(MouseEvent.BUTTON1); //1024  
int c = InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK; //8  
// works on mac  
Robot r = new Robot();  
r.mouseMove(500, 500);  
r.mousePress(1024);  
r.mouseRelease(1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that will help.

```
private final class ContractMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // Do whatever you want.
    }

}
```

And call this adapter in ur Swing code as

```
MouseAdapter mouseAction = new ContractMouseAdapter(Component);
```

Comment: I already a mouseAdapter class, the question is how to simulate a call to it's mousePressed method.