# KeyPress and KeyRelease in Robot.java

Tags: java, keyevent, awtrobot

In a button action I tried to add a keypress.

```
try{
    Robot robot=new Robot();

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);

    robot.mousePress(KeyEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(KeyEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Now I want the "A-Key" hold,In that case I commented out the third line
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
But the keypress doesn't need the keyRelease.So I didn't get the "A-Key" hold. In another case mousePress is pressed until the mouseRelease does not execute.Can anybody give me solution or explain what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a similar question, whose answer uses `Thread.sleep()` to keep the key pressed down: [Simulate a key held down in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784414/simulate-a-key-held-down-in-java) and this question: [How can I make Robot press and hold a mouse button for a certain period of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401467/how-can-i-make-robot-press-and-hold-a-mouse-button-for-a-certain-period-of-time)

Comment: I wonder it's not the similar question.My mousePress and mouseRelease worked. but the Keypress doesn't need the keyRelease. Even If I don't add the keyRelease it automatically release that key.