# How to click a mouse on the button on focus?

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium to upload a file.

```
driver.findElement (By.id("lll")).click(); 
// Now, a pop up window shows up
// The window has a button "Choose File" on focus
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouse // how can I click this button ? I tried KeyPress(Enter) but this click on "OK" by default
```

Also, the "Choose File" button has its `xpath` but I do not know how to switch from the browser to the pop up window

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a 'browse....' dialog? If so, don't click it - just send the file path to it.

Comment: @Arran I guess you are right. The id for the pop up window is `dialogTitleSpan` How can I send the path, could you give me an example Thank YO

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it's a standard "Browse...." file upload element.

In which case, you *should* (being the key word) not have to use any screen manipulation tools like the `Robot` class.

You should just be able to send the element a path to the file you want. Such as:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).sendKeys("C:\the\path");
```

If this is the case, *do not* click the element to open the popup window.

Comment: +1 Thank you. The code works. No exceptions thrown . However, it does not upload the file somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `robot.mousePress(int i)` and `robot.mouseRelease(int i)`.

A previous post with example code: [How can I make Robot press and hold a mouse button for a certain period of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401467/how-can-i-make-robot-press-and-hold-a-mouse-button-for-a-certain-period-of-time)