# How do you simulate a full click with Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, actionlistener

I am implementing some keyboard code for an existing java swing application, but I can't seem to get a keyboard press to execute the "mousePressed" action and "mouseReleased" action that are mapped to a JButton.  I have no problems clicking it for the "action_performed" with button.doClick(), is there a similar function for simulating the mouse presses? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445105/how-do-you-simulate-a-click-on-a-jtextfield-equivalent-of-jbutton-doclick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *simulate* mouse presses and mouse actions by using the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. It's made for *simulation* e.g. for automatically test user interfaces.

But if you want to share "actions" for e.g. buttons and keypresses, you should use an `Action`. See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Example on how to share an action for a Button and a Keypress:

```
Action myAction = new AbstractAction("Some action") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
    }
};

// use the action on a button
JButton myButton = new JButton(myAction);  

// use the same action for a keypress
myComponent.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"), "doSomething");
myComponent.getActionMap().put("doSomething", myAction);
```

Read more about Key-bindings on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Answer (score 3):

Look into using a [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to simulate keyboard presses and mouse activity.

- [How to use Robot](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t84094.html)
- [How to Control your Computers Mouse using the Robot class](http://javaprogrammingforums.com/java-se-api-tutorials/214-how-control-your-computers-mouse-using-robot-class.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could add a listener to your button:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ButtonAction {

private static void createAndShowGUI()  {

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("JAVA");
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton button = new JButton(" >> JavaProgrammingForums.com <<");
    //Add action listener to button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Execute when button is pressed
        System.out.println("You clicked the button");
        }
    });      

    frame1.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame1.pack();
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}`
```